# Passing Functions through Sub Procedure

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to call a function when running a sub proecudere, however, I keep getting an error message saying "Argument not optional", can someone help?

Code as follows:

```
Public Sub ret()

Dim FSO As New Scripting.FileSystemObject

Const cstrFolderF = "\\tblSCFLAGCHECKER.txt"


           If FSO.FileExists(cstrFolderF) Then
           DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE * FROM [tblSCFLAG_CHECKER]"
           DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, "tblSCFLAG_CHECKER", "tblSCFLAG_CHECKER", cstrFolderF, True
            changefieldnames
           Else
           'SCAnswer = MsgBox("SC Flags does not exist, do you wish to continue?", vbYesNo Or vbQuestion Or vbDefaultButton2)
        'If SCAnswer = vbNo Then Exit Sub
        End If
        End Sub

Private Sub changefieldnames()


Dim db As Database
Dim tdf As TableDef
Dim n As Object

Set db = CurrentDb
Set tdf = db.TableDefs("tblSCFLAG_CHECKER")
  For Each n In tdf.Fields
    If n.Name = "?Person ID" Then n.Name = "Person ID"
  Next n

Set tdf = Nothing
Set db = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Sure, just provide some necessary details.

Comment: edited question above

Answer (score 0):

Your `changefieldnames` function requires two arguments but you give none in the call after

```
       DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, "tblSCFLAG_CHECKER", "tblSCFLAG_CHECKER", cstrFolderF, True
        changefieldnames
```

As a remark: you should try to debug your code instead of just posting an error without even stating where exactly the error occurs.

Comment: changed and working fine, just had to take a step back.